# Changing what a button click does depending on number of total clicks

Tags: java, android, algorithm, android-button

I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to implement the following. I have a button, that makes an EditText visible on first click then after that will be implemented to manage the text entered into the text field.

I am using a counter to determine which actions take place within my `onClick` event using an if. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this?

The xml:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CLICK ME"
    android:onClick="clickMe"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="EDIT TEXT"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

The java:

```
static int clickCount =0;

public void clickMe (View view){

    if(clickCount==0) {
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mEditText;
        mEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Testing this method", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //TO DO SOMETHING MORE SIGNIFICANT.
    }

    clickCount++;
}
```

Basically, it doesn't matter what events I want to take place, ie the visibility of the EditText and handling the EditText text, but rather what is the best way to implement such a feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Yes, there is a better way. Forget keeping a `clickCount`. Just test for visibility of `mEditText` in the event handler.

```
public void clickMe (View view){
    EditText mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mEditText);
    if (mEditText.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        //TO DO
    } else {
        mEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```